# Bootstrap data-target Bug workaround

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Referencing to issue #19813 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19813), is there a known way to fix this behaviour?

I want to collapse multiple table rows and show the hidden ones by pressing a button.
Reduced Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/auzcxd0L/

```
data-target="#id1 #id2"
```

expands neither of them.

```
data-target="#id1"
```

or

```
data-target="#id2"
```

expands the specified row.

Changing

```
return selector ? $(selector)[0] : null;
```

in bootstrap.js to

```
return selector ? $(selector) : null;
```

unfortunately doesn't solve the problem

The used version is V4.0.3 Alpha

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:
Add an id to the button, like

```
id="expandbutton"
```

Now add a class to every element that should be collapsed, like

```
class="collapsedrow[...]"
```

and remove the data-stuff from the button.

Forked into a new jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z11h24f3/